# Is it possible to write a dataset as a .dif file in R?

Tags: r, file, export

I am wondering if it's possible to export a dataset from R as a .dif file. I know you can export it as a .csv file and as an excel file.

Comment: What is a `.dif` file? For use by what program? Any further details would be helpful. Do you mean this - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Interchange_Format ? If so, see `?read.DIF` for at least a start on the import side of things - there doesn't seem to be a corresponding `write.DIF`

Comment: Yeah, I meant a Data Interchange Format. Thanks for the information that is still helpful.